# Where statement from concat/union script

Tags: mysql

I have written the below SQL statement and get results, when I add the where name = statement it doesn't recognise 'name'

```
SELECT CONCAT( `Surname` , ' ', `firstname` ) AS NAME 
FROM Prospects
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT( `last_name` , ' ', `first_name` ) AS NAME 
FROM customer
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options.

Add a WHERE clause to each SELECT.  It's not possible to reference the result of the expression in the SELECT list by the assigned alias, in the WHERE clause of the same query. To specify the predicate in a WHERE clause, you would need to repeat the expression:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(p.surname,' ',p.firstname) AS NAME 
   FROM Prospects p
  WHERE CONCAT(p.surname,' ',p.firstname)  = ?
  UNION 
 SELECT CONCAT(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name)
   FROM customer c
  WHERE CONCAT(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name)  = ?
  ORDER BY 1
```

MySQL extends the SQL standard, and allows a HAVING clause to reference non-aggregate expressions that are not in a GROUP BY

```
 SELECT CONCAT(p.Surname,' ',p.firstname) AS NAME 
   FROM Prospects p
 HAVING NAME  = ?
  UNION 
 SELECT CONCAT(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name) AS NAME 
   FROM customer c
 HAVING NAME  = ?
  ORDER BY 1
```

To reference the alias by name in a WHERE clause, you could use an inline view. But note that there can be a significant performance penalty, because the predicate is *not* pushed into the inline view. That means that MySQL will materialize all of the rows from the view query as derived table, and then the outer query will run against the derived table. Don't do this, especially with large tables:

```
SELECT v.name
  FROM ( SELECT CONCAT(p.Surname,' ',p.firstname) AS NAME 
           FROM Prospects p
          UNION
         SELECT CONCAT(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name)
           FROM customer c
       ) v
 WHERE v.name  = ? 
 ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( Surname , ' ', firstname ) AS NAME FROM Prospects 
UNION 
SELECT 
    CONCAT( last_name , ' ', first_name ) AS NAME FROM customer 
WHERE 
    CONCAT( Surname , ' ', firstname ) = <statement> or
    CONCAT( last_name, ' ', firstname ) = <statement> 
ORDER BY name;
```